# Visual Assist vs Resharper

Tags: c++, c#, visual-studio, ide

Подскажите в чем отличие между этими двумя продуктами и что из этого в итоге лучше?

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм простой:

- Если пишете код на C#, то используйте *ReSharper*.
- Если пишете код на C++, то используйте *Visual Assist*.

И *ReSharper C++*, и *Visual Assist C#* являются попытками откусить кусок пирога у конкурента и не дотягивают до расширений, которые уже давно разрабатываются. Возможно, когда-нибудь это изменится, а пока у обоих продуктов своя специализация.

Для C# ещё есть *CodeRush*, к слову. Конкурент ReSharper, некоторым нравится.

Comment: Добавлю от себя, что вполне можно обойтись и встроенным редактором Visual Studio.

Comment: @VladD А можно и Блокнотом.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: Никогда не пользовалась подобными дополнениями, всегда хватало VS.

Comment: Чем `Assist` лучше `ReSharper C++`? У меня стоял `Assist`, теперь стоит `ReSharper C++`. Пока я отмечаю лишь положительные моменты.

Comment: @ixSci Сужу по комментариям на Хабре, если честно. Учитывая, что компания джетбрейн всерьёз взялась за плюсы (пишет ещё и IDE), то есть все шансы, что плюсовый решарпер (вскоре?) не будет уступать старому инструменту другой компании. P.S. Названия продуктов не следует форматировать как идентификаторы кода.